# Error occuring when loading photolibrary images : ERROR: FigCreateCGImageFromJPEG returned -12910. 423114 bytes. We will fall back to software decode

Tags: ios, image, alassetslibrary, photolibrary

I'm working with an application in which I'm loading images from photolibrary.

I'm using the following code for binding the image to imageView.

```
-(void)loadImage:(UIImageView *)imgView FileName:(NSString *)fileName
{
   typedef void (^ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock)(ALAsset *asset);
   typedef void (^ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock)(NSError *error);    

   ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
   {
     ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
     CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
     UIImage *lImage;
     if (iref)
     {
        lImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref scale:[rep scale] orientation:(UIImageOrientation)[rep orientation]];   
     }
     else
     {
        lImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Nofile.png"];
     }
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [imgView setImage:lImage];
     });
   };

   ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
   {
       UIImage *images = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Nofile.png"];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             [imgView setImage:images];
     });        
   };                   


    NSURL *asseturl = [NSURL URLWithString:fileName];

    ALAssetsLibrary *asset = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [asset assetForURL:asseturl
           resultBlock:resultblock
          failureBlock:failureblock];
}
```

But when I tried to run it, an error is coming and the application is crashing sometimes.
The error printed on console is:

** *** ERROR: FigCreateCGImageFromJPEG returned -12910. 423114 bytes. We will fall back to software decode.
Received memory warning.**
My photo library contains high resolution images and their size between 10-30 MB.

Comment: I take it that 10-30 meg is the size of the raw jpg file? remember...software decode is going to uncompress into a raw memory bitmap. a 30meg jpg file is probably 200-300meg in uncompressed/raw form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I fixed the issue.
I think the issue is with fetching the full resolution image.

Instead of :

`CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];`

I used:

```
CGImageRef iref = [myasset aspectRatioThumbnail];
```

And everything worked fine. No error in console, no crash, but quality/resolution of the image is reduced.

Comment: I need to keep the quality, what should I do to remove this error..? anys uggestions?

Comment: @NikitaP: yes, there is quality issues when you use the above method. But I didn't get any better way to do this

Comment: I got this error only once, when I ran the app again, it went off :). I am not sure what caused it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar error:

* ERROR: FigCreateCGImageFromJPEG returned -12909. 0 bytes. We will fall back to software decode.

app crush on call:

```
CGImageRef originalImage = [representation fullResolutionImage];
```

I fix it by replace to:

```
CGImageRef originalImage = [representation fullScreenImage];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[UIImage imageWithCGImage:]
```

`imageWithCGImage` is a stack memory function, it seems to overflow if the large image.
What about using the heap functions?.

```
lImage = [[[UIImage alloc]initWithCGImage:iref scale:[rep scale] orientation:(UIImageOrientation)[rep orientation]] autorelease];
```